# How to get a div or span class from a related span class?

Tags: html, css, selenium, beautifulsoup, request

I've found the lowest class: `<span class="pill css-1a10nyx e1pqc3131">` of multiple elements of a website but now I want to find the related/linked upper-class so for example the highest `<div class="css-1v73czv eh8fd9011" xpath="1">`. I've got the soup but can't figure out a way to get from the 'lowest' class to the 'highest' class, any idea?

```
<div class="css-1v73czv eh8fd9011" xpath="1">
 <div class="css-19qortz eh8fd9010">
  <header class="css-1idy7oy eh8fd909">
  <div class="css-1rkuvma eh8fd908">
  <footer class="css-f9q2sp eh8fd907">
   <span class="pill css-1a10nyx e1pqc3131">
```

End result would be:

INPUT- Search on on all elements of a page with class `<span class="pill css-1a10nyx e1pqc3131">`(lowest)

OUTPUT - Get all related titles or headers of said class.

I've tried it with if-statements but that doesn't work consistently. Something with an if class = (searchable class) then get (desired higher class) should work.

I can add any more details if needed please let me know, thanks in advance!

EDIT: Picture per clarification where the title(highest class) = "Wooferland Festival 2022" and the number(lowest class) = 253  [image: Listing, title, number]

Comment: Could you provide some context to clarify as well as some code please. Is header tag == to title? Is there a real world example? Is there only one pill? ... Thanks

Comment: @HedgeHog shouldn't `find_previous` work here?

Comment: @platipus_on_fire brothers in mind ;) but due to the ambiguities outlined, this would currently only lead to one assumption. So clarification would be great and will improve the question.

Comment: Truth is, bs4 docs could do with an improvement: many things are simply undocumented, or under-documented, like `find_previous`, or pseudo-selectors for instance. Anyway, `find_previous` doesn't work for me.

Comment: @HedgeHog Surely! The site has listing with a title and a number (see picture in OP). I'm finding and filtering the numbers with `[element.get_text() for element in soup.find_all(class_)]` ,adding it to a list and filtering everything under 50,then trying to get the title related to that number (Wooferland Festival 2022 for the image added). There are multiple pills so the list has multiple elements.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*As mentioned, question needs some more information, to give a concret answer.*

Assuming you like to scrape the information in the picture based on your example HTML you select your `pill` and use `.find_previous()` to locate your elements:

```
for e in soup.select('span.pill'):
    print(e.find_previous('header').text)
    print(e.find_previous('div').text)
    print(e.text)
```

Assuming there is a cotainer tag in HTML structure like `<a>` or other you would select this based on the condition, that it contains a `<span>` wit class `pill`:

```
for e in soup.select('a:has(span.pill)'):
    print(e.header.text)
    print(e.header.next.text)
    print(e.footer.span.text)
```

**Note:** *Instead of using css classes, that can be highly dynamic, try use more static attributes or the HTML structure.*

##### Example

*See both options, for first one the `<a>` do not matter.*

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
html='''
<a>
<div class="css-1v73czv eh8fd9011" xpath="1">
 <div class="css-19qortz eh8fd9010">
  <header class="css-1idy7oy eh8fd909">some date information</header>
  <div class="css-1rkuvma eh8fd908">some title</div>
  <footer class="css-f9q2sp eh8fd907">
   <span class="pill css-1a10nyx e1pqc3131">some number</span>
  <footer>
 </div>
</div>
</a>
'''

soup = BeautifulSoup(html)

for e in soup.select('span.pill'):
    print(e.find_previous('header').text)
    print(e.find_previous('div').text)
    print(e.text)

print('---------')
    
for e in soup.select('a:has(span.pill)'):
    print(e.header.text)
    print(e.header.next.text)
    print(e.footer.span.text)
```

##### Output

```
some date information
some title
some number
---------
some date information
some date information
some number
```